# mysql select query not working with limit and offset set via user variables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, user-variables

I'll be brief:

**WORKING**

```
SELECT p.id,
    p.name,
    cat.name `category`,
    prod.name `producer`,
    p.images,
    p.price,
    p.flag_avaliable,
    p.amount,
    p.description,
    p.options
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN product_category cat ON cat.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN product_producer prod ON prod.id = p.producer_id
ORDER BY @asc_or_desc
    limit 5 offset 6;
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
set @asc_or_desc = 'id desc ';
set @limit_number = 5;
set @offset_number = 6;
SELECT p.id,
   p.name,
   cat.name  `category`,
   prod.name `producer`,
   p.images,
   p.price,
   p.flag_avaliable,
   p.amount,
   p.description,
   p.options
FROM product p
         INNER JOIN product_category cat ON cat.id = p.category_id
         INNER JOIN product_producer prod ON prod.id = p.producer_id
ORDER BY @asc_or_desc
limit @limit_number offset @offset_number;
```

So, I need the 'not working' version to work. How can I do that?

I have the same error: `'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@limit_number offset @offset_number; END''`.

Why? Types are ok, you see... What the problem? Maybe values are substitute with some bug?

I'm using JetBrains DataGrip, MySQL 8.0.15.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL or built the query in the language of the client if there is any.

Comment: @stickybit, you mean prepared statements?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility.

Comment: @stickybit, Ok, that works. I thought, sql has more might

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using prepared statements have solved the problem. 
The code:

```
set @statement =
    concat('SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       cat.name  `category`,
       prod.name `producer`,
       p.images,
       p.price,
       p.flag_avaliable,
       p.amount,
       p.description,
       p.options
FROM product p
         INNER JOIN product_category cat ON cat.id = ?
         INNER JOIN product_producer prod ON prod.id = p.producer_id
ORDER BY id ',@asc_or_desc,'
limit ? offset ?');
prepare prepared from @statement;
EXECUTE prepared USING @category_id, @limit_number, @offset_number;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes, It doesn't work. Damn. How to fix it?